# S3 event trigger to different SNS topics

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an event in an S3 bucket that is triggered on every object creation. Now, I need to create another event that will only be triggered for specified subdirectory.

When I attempt to do that, I get an error

```
Configuration is ambiguously defined. 
Cannot have overlapping suffixes in two rules if the prefixes are overlapping for the same event type.
```

Since the first event is a catch-all, there is no prefix or suffix that I can specify to avoid this situation.

Do I have any options for creation of different events to this bucket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [this forum discussion](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=214437), what you are asking is not supported.

Here's [an alternative solution](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/fanout-s3-event-notifications-to-multiple-endpoints/) that could be used. For your use case, 2 Lambda functions would have to be subscribed to the SNS topic. One of them will work on the specified subdirectory, the other will act as your catch all.